# send html5 video back to start on mouse leave

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I'd like to send a video back to the start when the mouse leaves it, not sure how to do this, my code is as follows, this plays and pauses fine but doesn't send the video back to the start when leaving.

**JQuery**

```
 $(document).on("mouseenter", ".mammo-video", function(e){
      $(this).get(0).play();
 });


 $(document).on("mouseleave", ".mammo-video", function(e){
     $(this).get(0).pause();
 });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `mouseleave`:

```
$(this).get(0).currentTime=0;
//$(this).get(0).play(); //if you want it to play
```